# Convert a long list to a binary dataframe having duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr

According to this question and answer it is possible to convert a long list to a binary dataframe.

However how could it be possible to use it into a dataframe which contains the same value more than one time for every user?

Example of dataframe:

```
d_long <- data.frame( nameid = c("sally","sally","sally", "sally","Robert","annie","annie","annie"), value = c("product1","ra","ent","ra","ra","ra","product1","product1"))
```

> ```
> nameid    value
> 1  sally product1
> 2  sally       ra
> 3  sally      ent
> 4  sally       ra
> 5 Robert       ra
> 6  annie       ra
> 7  annie product1
> 8  annie product1
> ```

The expected output is this:

```
d_exist <- data.frame(nameid = c("sally","Robert","annie"), product1 = c(1,0,1), ra = c(1,1,1), ent = c(1,0,0))
```

> ```
> nameid product1 ra ent
> 1  sally        1  1   1
> 2 Robert        0  1   0
> 3  annie        1  1   0
> ```

But when I try this:

```
d_long %>% group_by(nameid, value) %>%
     mutate(count = n()) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     spread(value, count, fill = 0) %>%
     as.data.frame()
```

**I receive the error:**

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (7, 8), (2, 4)

**Is it right to use only**

```
d_long[!duplicated(d_long), ]
```

Comment: `table(d_long)` would take you closer.

Comment: You need a sequence column by group

Comment: something like this can help, I am unsure though `(table(d_long$nameid, d_long$value)> 0)+0`

Answer (score 1):

We can take the `distinct` and then do the `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
d_long %>%
  distinct %>% 
  mutate(n = 1) %>% 
  spread(value, n, fill = 0)
#    nameid ent product1 ra
#1  annie   0        1  1
#2 Robert   0        0  1
#3  sally   1        1  1
```